# Complex representation of a real wave

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, wave-equation, exponential-sum

I have the following formula for a wave: $u(x)=a \cos(kx-\omega t + \phi)$. I am trying to recover the complex representation of it $u(x)=\Re(a e^{i\phi}e^{i(kx-wt)}$. I started by using Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ to write $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ and plugging it in the original $u(x)$ formula.
I do not know how to proceed further from here, as there is a sum and not a product of exponentials. If I could just randomly change the sign of $e^{-i\theta}$ I would be done, but I do not know any rule that allows this...

Comment: Start with Euler's formula and ask what $\Re e^{i\theta}$ is.

Comment: I know that is the cosine. I just do not understand why $\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ reduces to $e^{i\phi}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$. I cannot think of a way that would be possible algebraically.

Comment: Maybe you have missed the fact that $e^{i\phi}e^{i(kx-\omega t)} = e^{i(\phi+kx-\omega t)}$ ?

Comment: you're overcomplicating this. $a\cos(kx-\omega t+\phi)=\operatorname{Re}(ae^{i(kx-\omega t+\phi)})$.